# Kotlin. Как расширить enum?

Tags: retrofit, enum, kotlin

Предыстория.

С помощью `retrofit` вытягиваю с сервера `json`. В этом `json` довольно большой набор параметров типа "статус", заданных в виде `integer`.

```
{
    "status":4,
    "type":7,
    "subType":1,
    "subStatus":9,
    и т.д.
}
```

Каждый из "статусов" описывается соответствующим `enum` и заполняется с помощью `GSONConverterFactory` с кучей подключенных адаптеров(ибо `integer` в `@SerializedName` не задашь).

Ну вот и получается, что у меня в каждом из этих `enum` присутствует такая функция

```
companion object {
        fun byCode(code: Int): AccidentType {
            for (value in AccidentType.values()) {
                if (code == value.code) return value
            }
            return AccidentType.UNKNOWN
        }
    }
```

Что никак не укладывается в парадигму переиспользования кода. (с кучей адаптеров тоже все здорово, но там не отмажешься насколько я понимаю)

**Вот и вопрос, как можно эту функцию реализовать так, чтоб одну на всех?**

Нюанс - в случае, если нужное значение не нашлось, необходимо возвращать некое значение "по умолчанию", но можно и просто `Exception` бросить, не хорошо, но, по идее, такой ситуации возникнуть не может.

В голову приходит что-то типа

```
fun <T:Enum<T>> enumByCode(code:Int, enum: T):T{
    for (value in T.values()) {
        if (code == value.code) return value
    }
    return T.default
}
```

Но оно совершенно ожидаемо ругается на невозможность `Т` содержать `companion object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что только пришло в голову.
Повесить extension function на java класс enum-a.

```
fun <T : Enum<*>> Class<T>.enumByCode(code: Int): T {
  for (value in this.enumConstants) {
    if (code == value.ordinal) return value
  }

  return this.enumConstants[0]
}
```

Единственное, определиться что возвращать как значение по умолчанию. У меня это самое первое значение каждого enum. Можно последнее.

Но можно и так:

```
enum class Unknown {
  UNKNOWN
}
fun <T : Enum<*>> Class<T>.enumByCode(code: Int): T {
  for (value in this.enumConstants) {
    if (code == value.ordinal) return value
  }

  return Unknown.UNKNOWN as T
}
```

Comment: Завтра попробую. Пока, в качестве workaround переписал бэкенд, чтоб числа в виде строк отдавал - стало возможным `@SerializedName` использовать. Но вот со значением по умолчанию беда. Думал интерфейс им общий сделать с методом "default", но столкнулся с тем, что Idea считает интерфейс к enum'у невозможным